# Shopify api authenticate customers

Tags: php, api, shopify

I have enabled customer accounts in my shopify account. I have developed another website where a situation came where i need a login field for the customers who have signed up in my shopify shop. I am not able to do this with shopify auth. Any solutions?

Comment: using the api, you can validate users  by `customer.email`.

Comment: @miglio I dont need user validation..i need user authentication

Answer (score 1):

Set your "other" website to be a subdomain of your Shopify store. When a known customer logs in to Shopify, set a cookie on the domain. The subdomain has access to that cookie, so clearly you can present a login if you want, or just authenticate them based on the fact they logged into Shopify.